# SQL, Get average job runtime from a log table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table LOGS with this attributes:

```
ID(int)
Date(datetime)
Core(int)
Source(string)
Message(string)
```

That table contains log entries from multiple jobs.
A job has multiple log entries, but the start/end entries always have the same message.

Example:

```
->1, 07.12.2016 10:49:00, 2, Some DLL, Calling Execute on CleanUp // Start
  2, 07.12.2016 10:49:01, 3, Other DLL, BLABLABLA
  3, 07.12.2016 10:49:10, 1, Other DLL, BLABLABLA
->4, 07.12.2016 10:50:15, 2, Other DLL, BLABLABLA // Job does sth.
->5, 07.12.2016 10:50:50, 2, Other DLL, Execution completed // End
```

The rows marked with an arrow belonging to the same job.
As you can see, a job starts with 'Calling Execute...' and ends with 'Execution completed'.

---

### What I want to achieve:

My task is to get the average job running times. The initial aproach was to filter with

```
WHERE Message LIKE '%JOBNAME%' OR Message LIKE 'Execution completed'
```

and comparing the dateTimes. This worked for some jobs, but some jobs run rarely so I only get "Execution completed" and the precision is not that great doing this manually.

At the end I want a list with following attributes:

```
ID(start log), 
Start-Date, 
End-Date, 
Core, 
Source-Start, 
Source-End, 
Message-Start, 
Message-End
```

So later it's easy to calculate the difference and do the avg on it.

### My idea

-> Get jobs by searching for a message.
-> Get a list with the message "Executing completed" having:

```
a higher ID (end log is always after start log)
a later datetime
the same core
```

### For example:

Having a job with the attributes

```
1, 07.12.2016 11:33:00, 2, Source 1, Calling Execute on job Cleanup
```

Then searching for all logs with

```
ID>1, 
dateTime>07.12.2016 11:33:00, 
Core=2, 
Message="Execution completed"
```

Picking the first item of that list should be the end log of the job

How can I do this with a sql query?

PS: I cannot change anything in the database, I can only read data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: That's a SQL client, not a DBMS. But as it can only connect to one DBMS product it's safe to assume you are using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the jobs using a correlated subquery to get the next end record.  The following shows how to get these fields:

```
select l.*, lend.*
from (select l.*,
             (select min(l2.date)
              from logs l2
              where l2.core = l.core and
                    l2.message like '% End'
                    l2.date > l.date
             ) as end_date
      from logs l
      where l.message like '% Start'
     ) l join
     logs lend
     on lend.core = l.core and lend.date = l.end_date;
```

This assumes that the date/time values are unique for a given "core".